# find the quantile percentage given a value

Tags: r

I have a data in the t vector and given the data I can get quantile

```
   t = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,21,22,23,2,23,4,4,4444)
  quantile(t,c(.3))
3
```

But I would like to do the opposite

I want provide 3 and have it return the quantile percentage

like  `somefunction(3,t)`  and the output is 30%

Is there a function for that?

Comment: You are asking for the `ecdf` function, which is offered as the inverse of quantile on the `?quantile` help page. It is returned as a decimal fraction but if you wanted it displayed as a "percentage" then just multiply by 100. (I suspect this is a duplicate.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `x` is the vector, and `x0` is the value you want to check, we can use

```
match(x0, sort(x)) / (length(x) + 1)
```

For your example:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,21,22,23,2,23,4,4,4444)
match(3, sort(x)) / (length(x) + 1)
# [1] 0.2941176
```

Answer (score 7):

Using the definition of the quantile:

```
sum(x<=3)/length(x)
```

gives you: `0.375`

Equivalent

```
f <- ecdf(x)
f(3) #0.375
```